# Is there any group with self-normalizing Sylow $p$-subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and assume that $G$ is not a $p$-group. I am looking for an example that for every Sylow subgroup $P$ of $G$,

$$N_G(P)=P$$.

I have doubt whether such groups exist.

Comment: I don't believe there are any examples. It is easy to see that a minimal example could not have an elementary abelian normal subgroup, and so it would have to have a minimal normal subgroup $N$ that was a direct product of isomorphic nonabelian simple groups, with $G/N$ a $p$-group. Then you could reduce to the case when $G$ is almost simple, which you would have to deal with using the classification of finite simple groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such groups. Let us a call a group *strange* if all of its Sylow subgroups are self-normalizing.

We first show that if $G$ is strange and $N \unlhd G$ then $G/N$ is strange. If not, then there exists $P/N \in {\rm Syl}_p(G/N)$ with $P/N \lhd K/N$ and $P \ne K$. Let $Q \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ with $QN=P$. Then, by the Frattini argument, $K = N_K(Q)N$, so $Q \ne N_K(Q)$, contradicting $G$ strange.

Now let $G$ be a group of minimal order that is strange and not a $p$-group, and let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then, since $G/N$ is strange, it must be a $p$-group for some prime $p$. Since $G$ is not a $p$-group, $N$ is not a $p$-group, and if $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(N)$ for some $q \ne p$, then $Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(G)$ and, by the Frattini Argument, $G=N_G(Q)N$. Hence, since $G$ is strange, we must have $G=N$ and $G$ is simple.

In fact $G$ is nonabelian simple and it is known from the classification that $G$ has a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ for some prime $p$. (See, for example, the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109611/cyclic-sylow-p-subgroup).) But now, by Burnside's Transfer Theorem, $P$ cannot be self-normalizing in $G$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, Derek. Really good answer.

Comment: I thik it very unlikely that this could be proved without using the classification!

Comment: If $H$ is Hall-$\pi$ subgroup of $G$, By induction $N_H(P)$ grows. Hence, only hall subgroups of $G$ are sylow subgroups and $G$. Can you see a contradiction from there ?

Comment: I can't see how to make any progress with a hypothetical unknown simple group.

Comment: @DerekHolt See Theorem 8.15 in Huppert and Blackburn's Finite Groups III for a proof without the classification.

Answer (score 1):

What about $G=S_3$ and $P=\{(1),(12)\}$? Or do you mean for *every* prime $p$ dividing $|G|$? If so then see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-04/S0002-9939-03-07161-2/S0002-9939-03-07161-2.pdf). It is proved (Corollary 1.3)) that if $p$ and $q$ are different primes dividing the order of $G$, and $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $Q \in Syl_q(G)$, then one of $P$ and $Q$ **cannot** be self-normalizing.

Comment: Thanks Nicky. What I mean is for every prime dividing order of $G$.